# Is there a more efficient way of validating whether duplicate values exist (Java)?

Tags: java

I need to validate that a list of ID's given doesn't contain any duplicate values. My attempt to do this can be shown here:

```
public void validate(RecordCollection collection)
        throws BusinessException {

    LinkedHashMap<Long, Long> existingIds = new LinkedHashMap<Long, Long>();

    for (Record record : collection.getArrayList()) {

        // check that you don't have two records with the same id
        if (existingIds.containsKey(record.getID())) {
            throw new BusinessException("records must be unique.",
                    ExceptionCodes.RECORDS_MUST_BE_UNIQUE);
        }

        //add the id to the map of existing ids
        existingIds.put(record.getID(), vo.getID());

    }
```

Is there a more efficient way of implementing this validation?

Comment: `existingIds.containsKey(record.getID())` looks fine to me.

Comment: `List<E> list = collection.getArrayList();
Set<E> set = new HashSet<E>(list);
if(set.size() < list.size()){
    /* There are duplicates */
}`

Comment: If your IDs are all between 0 and N, you could also use an array of booleans for constant-time lookup.

Comment: You can also check the return value of `existingIds.put(record.getId(), vo.getId())`. If it is not `null`, you have a duplicate.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot this does not shortcut, though.

Comment: If you don't want to allow duplicates in `RecordCollection` then don't use a `List` in there. A `Set` does not allow duplicates in the first place.

Comment: Using a Set instead of a List for the collection of Record objects in the first place would avoid the need for this validation. That's not always convenient though.

Comment: You can set initial capacity of `LinkedHashMap` to size of `collection` to prevent resizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is, with only a slight modification:

```
for (Record record : collection.getArrayList())
    if (existingIds.put(record.getID(), vo.getID()) != null)
        throw new BusinessException("records must be unique.",
            ExceptionCodes.RECORDS_MUST_BE_UNIQUE);
```

A `Map`'s `.put()` operation returns the previous value for the key. If there was no entry, `null` will be returned. And here, as you don't have `null` values, it means that if the return code is NOT `null`, you have a duplicate.

(also, why a `LinkedHashMap`? Your method returns `void`, so insertion order does not matter; just use a `HashMap`)

(also also, as suggested, when building the map, initialize its size to that of the collection you are checking)

Comment: I doubt if there will be a significant performance difference between these two approaches...

Comment: @Thihara well, you do only one unicity check for the key, not two

Comment: Good point about the LinkedHashMap v just an ordinary HashMap

Comment: I would improve that by setting initial capacity to the map to prevent resizing and rehashing..

Comment: Implementation details: if `ExceptionCodes` is an enum, you could bundle both the message and the code in it, and even make it generate the exception (something like `throw ExceptionCodes.RECORDS_MUST_BE_UNIQUE.asException())`)

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would think about a Set of the id's.
The add-method returns a boolean, if the value already existed or not.

So you can use the collection whereever you want and if the add returns a "false" you throw the exception.

About the implementation:
The RecordCollection should be a Set and checks the ids on it's own. So the validation-method is a private part of the RecordCollection and when an element is added, the exception will be thrown if needed.
The validation-loop is avoided at all.

An if you can't add the validation to the collection, then there is a subclass "IdenticalIDRecordCollection"

Comment: The `Set` is a trap, in particular a `HashSet`: it uses a `HashMap` internally... Well, at least, with Sun's JDK it does.

Comment: What I ment: Here the collection (parameter of the method) is built and afterwards it is validated. Why? Just add it to a set and check if it did. One step without an additional iteration.

Comment: And one more: The RecordCollection could do the check on it's own. No validation somewhere else.

Comment: @fge It does, but why is that a trap? A `Set` needs to validate that a new entry does not exist and the fastest way in terms of O notation is using a Hash-Whatever to do so. If it would be based on a simple array it would need to iterate over all elements. There is also `Collections.newSetFromMap(Map<E, Boolean> map)` that allows using any `Map` to build a `Set`

Comment: @zapl I was referring to the "efficiency" part. Although I suspect that in the OP's case, such a check could be done elsewhere in an even more efficient manner...

Comment: @fge: Avoiding the validation-loop is the most efficient way! One Check when set, thats it. Running of a given list two times cost more resources than checking on hash-value.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Set set=new HashSet<>(collection.getArrayList());
 System.out.println(x.size()==set.size());
```

prints true if no dublicates

Comment: Except that this will swallow all entries from the arraylist. Not really more efficient...

Comment: It is not necessary to add all items when we find first duplicate.

Comment: but this code does add all items to the set - or at least tries to